# Java HEX to ASCII conversion, for loop and other info needed

Tags: java, for-loop, hex

I am trying to get my program to spit out in something like this, This is HEX to ASCII or character conversion. Just need help. Please tell me when my for loops keeps going wrong.

```
Please enter the string to convert:  
a+b%3A4865792074686973206973206a7573742061207072616374696365
a b:Hey this is just a practice
```

but I get this below :(

```
Please enter the string to convert: 
a+b%3A4865792074686973206973206a7573742061207072616374696365
a b%3A4865792074686973206973206a7573742061207072616374696365:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Here is my code

```
public class Unmangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner webinput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the string to convert: ");
        String input = webinput.nextLine();
        Unmangle.Unmangler(input);
        String result = Unmangle.Unmangler(input);
        System.out.println(result);

    }

    // For example, unmangle("a+b%3A") should return "a b:".

    public static String Unmangler(String input) {

        // if(input.contains("%"))
        int place = input.indexOf("%");
        StringBuilder outputbuild = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder S;

        for (int i = place; i < input.length(); i += 2) {
            String output = input.substring(place + 1, place + 3);
            outputbuild.append((char) Integer.parseInt(output, 16));
        }

        String result = input.replace("+", " ") + outputbuild;

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. In your `for` loop you need to start from next letter after `%` so it should be

   ```
   for (int i = place + 1; i < input.length(); i += 2) {
   //           ^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. In iterations you should use `i` to determine indexes to substring, not `place`.
   BTW since `i` started from `place + 1` indexes wont be `i+1, i+3` but `i, i+2`

   ```
   String output = input.substring(i , i + 2);
   ```
3. Last change would be getting only part before `%` (including it) before replacing `+` with space and including decoded string

   ```
   String result = input.substring(0, place + 1).replace("+", " ") + outputbuild;
   ```

So try changing your `Unmangler` method to

```
public static String unmangler(String input) {

    StringBuilder outputbuild = new StringBuilder();

    int place = input.indexOf("%");
    for (int i = place + 1; i < input.length(); i += 2) 
        outputbuild.append((char) Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i , i + 2), 16));

    return input.substring(0, place + 1).replace("+", " ") + outputbuild;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not intending this to be a rival answer.  It's just that I don't have enough reputation to post a comment yet, and there is one facet missing from the answer above, which is that in the for loop you need i < input.length() - 1, rather than i < input.length(), since when i reaches input.length() - 2, input.substring(i , i + 2), 16)) will run from index i to index i + 1, which is what you want, since the index of the final element in the string is input.length() - 1.  Otherwise you get a NumberFormatException.